# Htaccess redirect and remove last 5 characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have 20k+ indexed pages but ~200 have */feed/* added at the end:

```
http://www.domain.com/page-ID-TITLE/feed/
ID and TITLE are dynamic.
TITLE can have multiple words, it doesn't have a fixed length: word1-word2-.....
```

The normal URL is:

```
http://www.domain.com/page-ID-TITLE/
```

The problem is that I get duplicated content on those pages, how can I redirect the URLs with feed at the end to the normal URL?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, actually. You don't need to specify the count of characters - only define what they are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+)/feed/?$ $1 [R=301]
```

I would suggest that you use the `[R]` flag instead of the `[R=301]` flag whilst testing on a production site. If it works, then switch it to the latter flag.